# how to check service state using vbscript?

Tags: service, vbscript, wmi, status, wmi-query

Is there anyway to check the status of service using vbscript ? I would like to have a function for each possible service state :
[LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee126211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Any help would be great. I did write a function for checking if service is stopped :

```
Public Function IsServiceStop(ByVal serviceName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objServices, service
    Set oWmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set objServices = oWmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service where Name='" & serviceName & "'")
    For Each service In objServices
        IsServiceStop = (service.Started = False)
        Exit Function
    Next
    IsServiceStop = True
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

Comment: WMI itself is a service. It may not be available. `Windows Management Instrumentation`

Comment: @Azevedo While it's true that WMI service may not be running, if that's the case, so much stuff doesn't work that it's not worth worrying about in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). All you need to do is check the `State` property of the service object:

```
serviceName = "..."

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
state = wmi.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & serviceName & "'").State
WScript.Echo state
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ='" & strServiceName & "'")

For Each objService in colListOfServices

   status = objService.State

Next

Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "startService", "Service status " & status
```

Answer (score 2):

```
' Michael Maher 
' 3/10/07 
' Checks if services exists and is running 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name='Messenger'")  
nItems = colRunningServices.Count  

' If the collection count is greater than zero the service will exist. 

If nItems > 0  Then 

For Each objItem in colRunningServices 

If objItem.State = "Stopped" Then 
Wscript.Echo objItem.DisplayName & " Installed/Stopped" 
ElseIf objItem.State = "Started" Then 
Wscript.Echo objItem.DisplayName & " Installed/Running" 
End If 
Next 

Else 
Wscript.Echo "Service Not Installed" 
End If
```

Here is the [source](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/01fcf945-ad73-44e0-8cb5-152432bc6bcf)